# Downloading .xlsx attachment from Outlook of Specific Date using Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-4.0

I have the below script. This $Tests shows the list of .xlsx attachment of specific date but is not able to download and throws an error. Please find the below script.

```
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$olDefaultFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]
$outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$mapi = $outlook.GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)
$inbox = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$FilePath= "c:\temp\Test\"
$subfolder = $inbox.Folders | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq “Test”}
$mail=$subfolder.Items |Select-Object -Property "ReceivedTime",@{name="Attachments";expression={$_.Attachments|%{$_.DisplayName}}} | Where-Object{$_.attachments -match ".xlsx" -and ($_.receivedtime -match "9/15/2020")} | Select-Object "attachments"
$Test = $mail.attachments
foreach ($out in $test) {$_.attachments|foreach {
Write-Host $_.filename
$Filename = $_.filename
If ($out.Contains("xlsx")) {
$_.saveasfile((Join-Path $FilePath "$out")) }}}
```

I am able to filter the .xlsx Attachments with Specific Date. But after this, I don't know how to save/download them.

Comment: Please paste your code in your question rather than to add it like a screenshot. If someone wants to use the code for editing it needs to be as text and not as pic. When inserted in your question, mark the code and press CTRL+K in order to format it as code.

Comment: in your for loop you reference to `$email` but int the previous line you use `$mail`? maybe that's the problem? and please - as @Adis1102 said - paste your code in the question.

Comment: Hi, Code has been updated. Please look into it

Comment: so what is the output of your current script?

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:17 char:5
+     $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $FilePath "$out")) }}}
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with com objects can be rather frustrating in powershell. I recommend you get extremely familiar with `Get-Member`. You really have to interrogate each object. I've simplified your script as well as tested thoroughly. It will download each matching attachment (name) from each match email (received date)

```
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$olDefaultFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]
$outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$mapi = $outlook.GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)
$inbox = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$FilePath= "c:\temp\Test\"
$subfolder.Items | Where-Object {$_.receivedtime -match "9/20/2020" -and $($_.attachments).filename -match '.xlsx'} | foreach {
    $filename = $($_.attachments | where filename -match '.xlsx').filename
    foreach($file in $filename)
    {
        Write-Host Downloading $file to $filepath -ForegroundColor green
        $outpath = join-path $filepath $file
        $($_.attachments).saveasfile($outpath)
    }
}
```

You may use this for more of an "in-line" approach.

```
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$olDefaultFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]
$outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$mapi = $outlook.GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)
$inbox = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$FilePath= "c:\temp\Test\"
$subfolder.Items | Where-Object {$_.receivedtime -match "9/20/2020" -and $($_.attachments).filename -match '.xlsx'} | foreach {
    foreach($attachment in $($_.attachments | where filename -match '.xlsx'))
    {
        Write-Host Downloading $attachment.filename to $filepath -ForegroundColor green
        $attachment.SaveAsFile((join-path $FilePath $attachment.filename))
        
    }
}
```